# CreateUserWizard and ActiveIndex in CreateUserError event

Tags: asp.net, createuserwizard

I have an CreateUserWizard, which has 4 steps, when error occured, In CreateUserError event, I want to set current step to second step, so I simply use

```
 RegisterUser.ActiveStepIndex = 1;
```

But when error occurs wizard stay at last step at this code does not work. Any suggestion?